# Docker: Reconnect new postgres container to existing Data container

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I have 3 docker containers. One running django, another running postgres and third is a data container for the postgres. I'm using docker-compose to link them up.

***docker-compose.yml***

```
dbdata:
  image: postgres
  container_name: dbdata_container
  volumes:
    - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  command: true

db:
  image: postgres
  container_name: postgres_container
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
  volumes_from:
    - dbdata

web:
  build: .
  container_name: django_container
  command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
  volumes:
    - .:/code
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
  links:
    - db
```

I have mistaken deleted my postgres container.

How to create a new postgres container which connects to existing data container?

I have tried running:

```
docker-compose up
```

It fails with following error:

```
web_1    | django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known
```

When I connect to postgres using PgMastero I could only see any tables in it.

Kindly help

Comment: Jahan, unless you deleted your local directory ./data, your database will be intact. Check if your the db container has permission to write onto the volume.

Comment: thanks, i think it doesn't have to do anything with permissions. I run all three containers as the same user for now, which is root infact. @ThiagoKronig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out a work around. Updating it here so it might help others who might face same issue.

I think links are getting messed up when once **postgres** container is removed.

So if I do `docker-compose up`, docker is unable to link with db container which I suppose is still pointing with deleted container or the new container is given different link name.

Deleting all the three containers and doing `docker-compose up` does the trick. I am not sure why is this, may be some bug in docker-compose module.